# Insert rows dynamically in VBA with formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have a row(A7:O7), based on the number of rows in my dictionary I need to copy these many number of rows in my heart with the same formatting as Row(A7:O7).
My code below is just copying the colors of the cells and the formatting of numbers. Can someone help please?

```
Dim j As Integer
j = dRpt.Count
Set r = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sht1").Range("a7")
Do
    Range(r.offset(1,0),r.offset(j,0).entirerow.insert
    Set r = Cells(r.Row + j + 1, 1)
    If r.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then

    End If
    Exit Do
Loop
```

Comment: Formulas not getting copied using this code .only the colors get copied

Comment: Even the border formatting not getting copied

Comment: Do you want to copy the formatting from row 7?

Comment: I am using my  phone because of which am not able to proofread and format it properly.Sorrg about that.

Comment: Yes I want to copy the formatting from the row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will insert `j` rows below "A7:O7" whose cells in columns "A:O" have same formatting of "A7:O7"

```
j = Drpt.Count
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sht1").Range("a7:o7")
    .Offset(1).Resize(j).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown, .Offset(-1).Cells
End With
```

Comment: @ThomasInzina, why should that _probably_ be?

Comment: I was joking about my answer,  There isn't a reason for me to post it.  Yours is better.  Actually there is no reason.  It'd probably throw an error with my suggestion.  Ugh..I'm getting sloppy.  My apologize again.